# PickerView - ViewController does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource

Tags: swift, datasource, uipickerview

I am having at bit og trouble with my `PickerView`. First my `ViewController` does not accept `UIPickerViewDataSource` no matter what I do. Second, the PickerView will only show the first row. I need it to show both rows and display in one TextField called school

What do I do wrong ?????

Can anyone help me before I go crazy

```
enter code here
    private let typeComponent = 0
    private let areaComponent = 1
    private let typeOption = ["HighSchool of", "College of", "University of"]
    private let areaOption = ["Miami", "Los Angeles", "New York"]

        // PickerView - School  2 af 5
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    // PickerView - School  3 af 5
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == typeComponent {
            return typeOption.count
        } else {
            return areaOption.count
    }
    }
    // PickerView - School  4 af 5
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == typeComponent {
            return typeOption[row]
        } else {
        return areaOption[row]

    }
    }
    // PickerView - School  5 af 5
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
//        school.text = pickOption[component][row]

        let typeRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: (0))
        let areaRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: (1))
        let type = typeOption[typeRow]
        let area = areaOption[areaRow]
        school.text = "\(type)\(area)"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        //Placeholder TextView Interest and about 1 ag 3
        Interest.delegate = self
        Interest.text = "What are your interests..."
        Interest.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

        about.delegate = self
        about.text = "Tell about yourself..."
        about.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

        //PickerView School  1 af 5
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        school.inputView = pickerView
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement all the required methods of `UIPickerViewDataSource`. If you not conform to `UIPickerViewDataSource` it will give you error.

Methods which is Required to implement in your conforming class

in **Swift 2.0**

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

in **Swift 3.0**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class conforms to `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
//
}
```

Updated:

For **Swift 3** you have to use this datasource function:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
}
```

and not the one you used.

Comment: As I wrote, the ViewController does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource

Comment: Are you using Swift 3?

Comment: Yes I am using Swift 3

Comment: Your class can not conforms to UIPickerViewDataSource because you're using Swift 2 datasource method.

Comment: But how do I align both rows to center in PickerView